# SC 9.0.2 SIF xConnect Stalls During Web Deploy

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

Using the following in PS1 script:

```
Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
$prefix = "bc2018"
$PSScriptRoot = "D:\resourcefiles"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect"
$xConnectCertName = "$prefix.xconnect_client"
$SqlServer = "BCCMPTLCD4DB"
$SqlAdminUser = "Admin"
$SqlAdminPassword="sp20019!"
$SiteName = "$prefix.xconnect.org"
```

## Install client certificate for xconnect

```
$certParams = @{
  Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"
  CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client"
}

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose<br />
```

## Deploy xconnect instance

```
$xconnectParams = @{
   Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp1-collection.json"
   Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (OnPrem)_xp1collection.scwdp.zip"
   LicenseFile = "D:\resourcefiles\license.xml"
   Sitename = $SiteName
   XConnectCert = $xConnectCertName
   SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
   SqlServer = $SqlServer
   SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
   SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
}

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose<br />
```

It gets to the follow spot in the script and then just stalls:

[image]

Comment: Try waiting a bit, in 9.0.2 it takes more time than 9.0.1. Check this for easy install https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/sitecore-9-installation-download-install-validate-done/

Comment: I waited an hour an nothing happened.  Sadly the company I work for has all wordpress sites blocked.

Comment: sad to know. you can try this one. it is WIP/migration though,   http://www.isaadansari.com/sitecore-9-installation-download-install-validate-done/

Comment: To be on the same page, I am installing the xp scaled version to a production environment.  Almost all of the information I have gleaned from the net is for xp single installs.

Answer (score 1):

We have found that Database Change audit stalls the database.  In order to solve this issue we had to turn off that audit.  Here is what we did (our database is called *DB_Changes*):

1. Create new query against master database:

   `ALTER SERVER AUDIT DB_Changes WITH (STATE = OFF)`
2. Run the Powershell script for xConnect.
3. After script completes run the following query to re-enable audits:

   `ALTER SERVER AUDIT DB_Changes WITH (STATE = ON)`